# How to separe two values from .txt to two different files?

Tags: python, awk, extract

I have a set of my user database dumps in **.txt** files (let's assume in the **C:\Dumps** folder)

The structure of all **.txt** files is identical:

```
login:password
login:password
login:password
```

My question is what is the easiest way to separate logins from all files to
"logins.txt" and separate passwords for "passwords.txt"?
These are data for statistical purposes, so no order [ultimately will be sorted anyway]

I tried :

```
gawk.exe -F: "{print $ 1}" dump1.txt > logins1.txt
gawk.exe -F: "{print $ 2}" dump1.txt > passwords1.txt
gawk.exe -F: "{print $ 1}" dump2.txt > logins2.txt
gawk.exe -F: "{print $ 2}" dump2.txt > passwords2.txt
```

and the method is effective, but due to the number of files, I wanted to ask about a simple method to automatically separate these two data from the files that I have in this folder.

Comment: It probably makes sense to post one question at a time on SO, as it helps users to be specific with the response. It may help narrow the scope of your question to #1 for this post and then you can ask another question separately. It also helps if you post what you tries so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run awk on multiple files and also action redirection from within awk code and so:

```
awk -F: '{ split(FILENAME,map,".");fileno=substr(map[1],length(map[1]));print $1 > "login"fileno".txt"; print $2 > "password"fileno".txt" }' dump*.txt
```

We set the field delimiter to : and then use awk's reserved FILENAME variable to track the existing file being processed. With this we get the file name prefix by splitting the filename in an array map, using awk's split function and referencing map[1]. We then further process this with awk's substr function to get the file number from the last character of the file prefix. We utilise this filno variable to output $1 to the login file and $2 to the password file.

Comment: Execute this give me an error
awk: '{
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: I've just noticed that this is the Windows version of gawk. This is probably the issue you are having,

Comment: I have to run your code into msys now, and that's work! Many thanks for that!